# Shopware 6 Xampp installation: This page is not available

Tags: installation, xampp, shopware6

i want to install shopware 6 on xampp. Now when i want to start the installprocess with calling the /public route i've got everytime the message that **this page is not available**.

What can i do?

Comment: What did you do so far? Where did you extract the ZIP? What is your DocumentRoot in XAMPP?

Comment: Hi Alex, I downloaded shopware 6 community edition from shopware download site and extracted it in the XAMPP htdocs folder.  My DocumentRoot is C:/xampp/htdocs

Answer (score 1):

Hm, based on you saying "calling the /public route" I assume you are trying something like `http://127.0.0.1/public` ? If so, you should not be calling the public folder, it redirects to it internally. Just calling the `http://127.0.0.1` should work. You could also try explicitly calling the `http://127.0.0.1/index.php` file.
Shopware 6 also has a nice step by step [article](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/first-steps/installing-shopware-6) on the installation. Happy testing!

Comment: Hey augsteyer,

thanks for your answer. I changed my operating system to macOs. There I'm using docker with the bind mounting now.

Comment: Good call. Although, SW also does not recommend using bind-mounting on mac due to performance impart, and using regular ol' SFTP instead, see: https://docs.dockware.io/tips-and-tricks/performance-on-mac